# Update entry in database with excel cell value - Type mismatch

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to update a entry in a SQL database with a number from an Excel cell.

When the number I'm trying to send has no decimal part the code works fine, but if the number has decimal part, the macro returns a type mismatch error.

The type of the DB field is: (float, null).
The Cell in excel is formatted as "General". Formatting as "Number" gives the same result.

I already tried Range("C2").Value, but the result is the same. 
How should I read the value from the cell to send it properly to the DB?

```
Sub Send2DB()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim strResult As String

    ' Connection string.
    sConnString = .......

    ' Connection and Recordset 
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open connection
    conn.Open sConnString

    ' Read Cell
    Set rs = conn.Execute("UPDATE dbo.TABLE_A SET m_value = '" + Range("C2").Text + "' FROM TABLE_B AS b INNER JOIN TABLE_C AS c ON c.tc_id=b.tb_id WHERE c.ref_value LIKE '" + ActiveSheet.Name + "%'")
```

Comment: Could you add information about what DB are you working with? Or SQL database means SQL Server?

Comment: Yes it's an SQL Server Database. Compatibility level (from db info): SQL Server 2000 (80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be caused by the decimal separator. SQL Server expects '.' as decimal seperator so try to replace your separator (e.g. ',') to '.'

```
update = "UPDATE dbo.TABLE_A SET m_value = " & VBA.Strings.Replace(Range("C2").Value, ",", ".")

Set rs = conn.Execute(update)
```

This code will be executed on SQL Server as SQL:

```
UPDATE dbo.TABLE_A SET m_value = 8.8
```

Comment: At leat in my situation the database accepts correctly the number decimal separator ','. Using a '.' the execution gives a error... but a different one: "Error converting datatype varchar to float"

Comment: Your suggestion worked! Using a point '.'in the cell to separate the decimal part, the query picks the number that way but write it on the database with a ','. Don't know why but the fact is that this way the numbers are written correcty in the DB. thanks